# Pass range as parameters from excel to c# excel-dna

Tags: c#, excel-dna

[image]

i have chosen some rows  and cols in excel .
How can i pass them as parameter to a C# excel-dna function jusk like 'Sum(A1:C5)'?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code which can process parameter that was passed as a single cell or an array

```
public static object MyUDF(object param)
{
  if(param is Array){
    if (((Array)param).Rank == 2){
      int columnCount = ((Array)param).GetLength(1);
      int rowCount = ((Array)param).GetLength(0);
      for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
        {
            string cellValue = ((Array)param).GetValue(i, j).ToString(); 
        }
      }
    }     
  }else{
    string cellValue=param.ToString();
  }    
  return "done";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[ExcelFunction(Description = "get param type")]
        public static string getCSType(object o) {
            return o.GetType().ToString();
        }
i use this method to get the type of excel paramaters and found that cells chosen
 are passed as Object[,].if only one single cell is passed, then it'll be passed as string type.

In c# excel-dna you can use an object to receive a paramater of any type passed by excel.